# Is there any way to capture screenshot of home screen in Flutter, not the app screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using a screen recording plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_recording). I want to add a functionality to capture screenshot of the device's home screen or whatever the user is doing, and I've used different packages, but none of them worked as I wanted.